# What are the chances of a mother with $n$ children having at least $x$ daugthers?

Tags: combinatorics

A woman has $n$ children. What are the chances of **at least** $x$ of them being girls?

If the problem didn't have the "at least", I could simply use Pascal triangle formula

$$ C(n,x) = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} $$

and divide the result by $2^n$.

But I'd have to repeat that for $x$, $x+1$, ..., $n$, and sum all the resulting probabilities.

Is there a single formula that gives me the desired probability?

Comment: For small numbers, it's best to just add the individual cases.  For large numbers you could use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.

Comment: The exact answer comes from the sum you're describing. It's the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). You can use the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) to the binomial distribution if $n$ is large.

Comment: It doesn't sound like $n$ can be very large in this context

Comment: Of course you have to know the probability of a child being a girl. It is usually not exactly $1/2$. According to recent statistics there are 107 boys to 100 girls born worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Binomial distribution to calculate the probability. We know probability of boy= Probability of girl=$\frac{1}{2}$

So we can write
$$(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^n=^nC_0(\frac{1}{2})^n+.....+^nC_n(\frac{1}{2})^n$$.

To get the probability of atleast $x$ girls we have to add the terms $(\frac{1}{2}^n) ^nC_x $   upto  $  (\frac{1}{2}^n)^nC_n$ .
We can also determine probability of exactly $x$ girls by calculating the $(x+1)$th term.